# How can the generic Map for the font attributes be specified?

Tags: java, generics

I have this method which jdk1.6 complains (no error just warning) about the generic type parameterizing is not used in the Map and ...:

```
public static Font getStrikethroughFont(String name, int properties, int size)
    {
        Font font = new Font(name, properties, size); 

        Map  attributes = font.getAttributes(); 
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON); 
        Font newFont = new Font(attributes); 
        return newFont;             
    }
```

Then I changed to the following:

```
public static Font getStrikethroughFont2(String name, int properties, int size)
    {
        Font font = new Font(name, properties, size); 

        Map<TextAttribute, ?>  attributes = font.getAttributes(); 
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON); 
        Font newFont = new Font(attributes); 
        return newFont;             
    }
```

but the

```
attributes.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON);
```

statement is not valid anymore.

`TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON` is a Boolean.

How can I use Generic Type feature in above method? I have looked at the Core Java book but didn't find an answer. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Will the value you are putting to the Map always be a `TextAttribute`?

Comment: What type of error is being thrown? See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you should be using is [`font.deriveFont(map)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont%28java.util.Map%29).

```
public static Font getStrikethroughFont2(String name, int properties, int size)
{
   Font font = new Font(name, properties, size); 
   Map<TextAttribute, Object>  attributes = new HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>();
   attributes.put(TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH, TextAttribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON); 
   Font newFont = font.deriveFont(attributes);
   return newFont;             
}
```

This will solve your generics problem.  The derive font will copy the old font, and then apply the attributes you supplied it.  So, it will do the same thing you are trying to do using the `Font` constructor.

Answer (score 5):

You can't `put` in that map. It is meant just for reading.

The map you can use to put attributes is `Map<String, Object>`

If you need to get the existing map and create a font with its attributes + additional ones, use:

```
Map<TextAttribute, Object> map = 
   new HashMap<TextAttribute, Object>(font.getAttributes());
```

Comment: +1 This is a good context-insensitive answer (i.e. answering the generics problem specifically).  `deriveFont` is probably a better option all around.

Comment: true. I +1'ed @jjnguy for the better context-sensitive answer, but will still keep mine for reference

Comment: Hmmm, so you can construct a `Map<Key, Object>` out of a `Map<Key, ?>` interesting.  (`+1`)

Comment: ye,s it's because you can read Objects from the ?, but you can't put any (it's an "unknown type", rather than "any type")

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've understood the question well but how about doing this:

```
Map<TextAttribute, Object>
```

Every object has Object as Superclass and you anyway can't put any primitive types in a Map. So with Object, you get everything !

Comment: That won't compile as `Font.getAttributes()` returns a `Map<TextAttribute, ?>`.

Comment: @Dalshim This means you have to also add a cast to `font.getAttributes()` which will generate a compiler warning.